# Problem loading images in IE when using SharePoint hosted Add-ins with JSOM cross domain library

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, cross-domain, ie

I have a problem in displaying images in IE, I am developing a SharePoint hosted Add-in, the Lists which contains all the data and the images are hosted in the root site collection and the Add-in is hosted in a sub site in the same site collection. I am loading the images from the Site Assets in the root site, it appears as X icon in IE, but it works perfectly in chrome and firefox.

I had to view every image separately in a new tab in IE so that it can be displayed on the page after that.

any one faced this problem before?!

Comment: open the browser console (F12) in IE, are there any errors?

Comment: @johnpan No errors in the console, and everything is working fine in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I can think a couple of reasons,

- The image is saved using the CMYK model. Try edit one image and save 
  in RGB mode and see if helps.
- Maybe has to do with image DOM lifecycle. Is the image gets loaded
  via script or is it defined in html?